# ayuda instalando una libreria en ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, lenguaje-compilado

Tengo dos preguntas la segunda es en caso no haya respuesta a la primera. Disculpa si las preguntas son algo tontas.
Mi objetivo es modificar una variable global usando el elf file de un programa basico e.j. hello_world.c
Por ahi vi que se puede usar readelf para buscar el address de la variable y usar un hex editor para modificar el valor creo pero para este caso no debo usar este metodo. Me tope con la libreria libelf de elftoolchain del link de abajo que al parecer tiene estas capacidades.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/elftoolchain/files/Sources/

Tambien dice que me baje y extraiga este folder(link de abajo) y lo ponga en el directorio ../../test/tet/tet3.8 lo cual hice.

http://tetworks.opengroup.org/downloads/38/software/Sources/3.8/tet3.8-src.tar.gz

Al bajarme los archivos de elftoolchain me encontre con un archivo "INSTALL", me baje todos los packages requeridos para ubuntu 14.04. Me fui al directorio donde me descarge el projecto e.j Home/Downloads/elftoolchain y le di pmake en el terminal como dice las instrucciones y me dio el sgt. error

```
pekoms@pekoms-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ cd elftoolchain-0.7.1
pekoms@pekoms-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/elftoolchain-0.7.1$ pmake
all ===> common
all ===> libelf
all ===> libdwarf
all ===> libelftc
/home/pekoms/Downloads/elftoolchain-0.7.1/libelftc/make-toolchain-version: 74: 
/home/pekoms/Downloads/elftoolchain-0.7.1/libelftc/make-toolchain-version: svnversion: not found
ERROR: cannot determine a revision number.
*** Error code 1

Stop.
pmake[1]: stopped in /home/pekoms/Downloads/elftoolchain-0.7.1/libelftc
*** Error code 1

Stop.
pmake: stopped in /home/pekoms/Downloads/elftoolchain-0.7.1
```

Mi primera pregunta es si alguien pudiera tratar de instalar el programa este porque tiene un libro de documentation de como usar las librerias, pero no dice mucho acerca de la instalacion y no e podido encontrar mucho en como corregir el problema. Sino se puede me gustaria saber si es possible referir solamente el libelf folder que tiene las librerias que necesito a un programa en gcc que use estas librerias.
Por ejemplo un programa que abre un elf file y que use las funciones de estas librerias. Yo solo uso IDE's como visual studio y no estoy muy familiarizado con GCC o linux. Aprecio cualquier respuesta gracias.